# How to scale SVG path in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, path, transform

I am creating an svg path in javascript like this:

```
var myPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
myPath.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "myPath");
myPath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M202.403,95.22c0,46.312-33.237,85.002-77.109,93.484v25.663l-69.76-40l69.76-40v23.494 \
    c27.176-7.87,47.109-32.964,47.109-62.642c0-35.962-29.258-65.22-65.22-65.22s-65.22,29.258-65.22,65.22 \
    c0,9.686,2.068,19.001,6.148,27.688l-27.154,12.754c-5.968-12.707-8.994-26.313-8.994-40.441C11.964,42.716,54.68,0,107.184,0 \
    S202.403,42.716,202.403,95.22z");
myPath.setAttributeNS(null,"transform","scale(0.1,0.1)");
myPath.setAttributeNS(null,"transform","translate(100,500)");
document.appendChild(myPath);
```

after creating the path I need to move and scale it. `myPath.setAttributeNS(null,"transform","translate(100,500)");` works fine but `myPath.setAttributeNS(null,"transform","scale(0.1,0.1)");` does not.

Any ideas on how to scale down the path? Thanks!

Comment: try `myPath.setAttributeNS(null,"transform","translate(100,500) scale(0.1,0.1)");`

Comment: @enxaneta yep.... that works, I feel so dumb :) anyways, thanks!

Comment: BTW it is not necessary to use `setAttributeNS()` for most attributes.  `myPath.setAttribute("transform","translate(100,500) scale(0.1,0.1)");` is equivalent and simpler.  You only need to use the NS one for attributes with a namespace, like `xlink:href`.