# How to create multiple SVG paths in Javascript with a function

Tags: javascript, svg, path, transform

I need to create strokes similar in length but of different angles of rotations so instead of having a several redundant lines of codes, I preferred using JavaScript to that as follows;

```
function stroke(rot) {
   var dash=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
   dash.setAttributeNS(null,"id","dash");
   dash.setAttributeNS(null,"d","M 180 0 L 200 0");
   dash.setAttributeNS(null,"transform","rotate(+"+rot+" 200 200)");
   dash.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","none");
   dash.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke","black");
   dash.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width","5");
   document.appendChild(dash);
}

for(i=0;i<360;i+=10) stroke(i);
```

i is the value to which the stroke will be rotated when stroke(i) will be called.

I checked a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590938/how-to-scale-svg-path-in-javascript) to fix my code but
unfortunately this doesn't woks, any solution to this ?

Comment: stroke-dasharray on a circle would be easier and you wouldn't need javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you trying to append paths into a document, not in SVG element.

```js
const svgTarget = document.getElementById("draw");

function stroke(rot) {
  let dash = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  dash.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "dash");
  dash.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M 180 5 L 200 5");
  dash.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "rotate(+" + rot + " 200 200)");
  dash.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
  dash.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "black");
  dash.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "5");
  svgTarget.appendChild(dash);
}

for (i = 0; i < 360; i += 10) stroke(i);
```

```html
<svg id="draw" viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="200px" height="200px"></svg>
```

Comment: Very good, that's fine
I would have upvoted if I had the required reputation, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since a parsed `<svg id="draw">` already is in the correct *NameSpace*;
you can add content with Strings, no need to add those `<path>` in the SVG NameSpace (again)

As Robert said, a `<circle>` with `stroke-dasharray` gives a better result (drawn paths are straight),
does not require JavaScript and can easily be changed.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray

```js
for (i = 0; i < 360; i += 10) {
  document.getElementById("draw")
          .innerHTML += `<path d="M180 5L200 5" 
                               transform="rotate(${i} 200 200)"
                               fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>`;
}
```

```html
<svg id="draw" viewBox="0 0 400 400" height="180px"></svg>

<svg id="circle" viewBox="0 0 400 400" height="180px">
  <circle stroke-width="5" r="197.5" fill="none" stroke="red" cx="200" cy="200" 
          pathLength="72" stroke-dasharray="1"/>
</svg>
```